# I couldn’t understand what “ you mustn’t let a few bad times dictate.” means

Tags: meaning, sentence

“You mustn’t let a few bad times dictate.” 
What does that mean? I read it somewhere.. but I can’t remember.. anyway “let a few bad times dictate”, this part a
Little hard to understand for me

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: It’s about a lover who spent hard time and they don’t wanna break up

Comment: google it: what do such and such lyrics mean

Comment: @Seokjin That sounds like the intended meaning of the quote: not to let those few bad times be the reason for their break-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is incomplete - due to lacking a reference to what is being dictated too:  e.g. A person , situation, etc.

But you can break down the statement:

> "You" - The target of the statement
>
> "Mustn't" - Contracted 'Must Not'
>
> "Let" - Past tense of "Allow, permit, etc."
>
> "A few" - A small number
>
> "Bad" - In this case: 'adverse, difficult, inopportune, etc.'
>
> "Times" - Periods
>
> "Dictate" - 'control or decisively affect; determine'

Comment: How is _let_ a past tense? It's simply an infinitive.